# trying to get a running time stamp on Qt

Tags: c++, qt, while-loop

I am trying to keep a running time stamp every so many milliseconds. This will eventually be attached to a temperature reading. Right now the time stamp is only displaying after the rest of my program has run and I need it to populate in real time. My updated code using QTimer is

```
QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT());

//delay set to space out time readings, can be adjusted
timer->start(750);

//Gets the time    
QTime time = QTime::currentTime();

//Converts to string with chosen format    
QString sTime = time.toString("hh:mm:ss:ms");

//displays current time in text edit box    
ui->tempTimeNoHeatMode->append(sTime);
//Pre heat turns on for selected # of seconds
   digitalWrite(2,1);
   delay(preHeat * 1000);
   digitalWrite(2,0);


   //Set loop to run while flow time is not 0
   while(flowTime > 0)
 {

   displayCurrentTime();

   //set zero pin to be high while flowtime is more than 0
   digitalWrite(0,1);

   flowTime--;

   // set second pin LED to flash according to dutyCycle
       digitalWrite(2,1);
       delay(onTime);
       digitalWrite(2,0);
       delay(offTime);

 }

 //turn zero pin low after flow time reaches 0
 digitalWrite(0,0);

}
```

The code controls two leds to represent a heater and water flow later in my project.I am using `QtCreator 4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the UI isn't updating is that you never cede control to the event loop, so the main thread doesn't have a chance to update the UI until after your code has executed.

There's two possible solutions here:

1. Move your existing code to a [background thread](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html) that fires a [signal](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) when the time has changed.  Then in the main thread, connect that signal to a slot that updates the UI.
2. Instead of an loop that winds up calling delay(), put all of this code into a function or method and use a [QTimer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html) to have it execute every 750 milliseconds.

Comment: I like method (2) the best, but for completeness there is also (hack-ish) method #3:  call qApp->processEvents() from inside the while loop

Comment: I tried to use QTimer, but it is still only populating after the whole code has ran.

Comment: Your update has more problems than the original -- not only are you still preventing the event loop from running, now you've added a QTimer that isn't connected to any slot.

Comment: I fixed the not calling a slot, just over looked it. Got the time running just have to redo some of my other logic thanks everyone.